# How to have NPC's move in?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I've been playing Skyrim, and got a house mod awhile back called Fjellsted. After roaming around, it's essentially a jarl's palace in comparison. But aside from the guards in the guard house, the inn keeper, and the farm owner, there are no NPCs here. seeing as the place has like, 10 bedrooms excluding the players,  I felt it would be cool to have NPC's move in and just live there. So, is there an in-game mechanic or a Mod I could use to have NPC, default or custom, move in and will the work on a modded house?

Comment: You could probably ask the developer to add the functionality (or add it yourself if you are up to it).

Comment: As far as I know and this is only talking about Xbox and I have clocked over 300+ hours of the game getting close to 100% complete, there is no in game mechanic for this kind of thing. Mod wise I would google it or go to a Skyrim Forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [mods steam page](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=133432493):

> *To be added*
>   Exterior - worker accomodation, Proper mine, NPC's
>   Interior - More NPC's, decoration fixes, misc navmeshing
>   Misc: Scripting, navmeshing, quests, story, etc.

So it looks like more NPCs are coming in time.

Comment: If navmeshing is "TBD", then *no* NPCs can function properly inside yet, even with external mods.

Comment: Alright then, but still would be nice to have a means of making NPCS change houses on command.

Comment: @user50144 I'm not sure that's technically feasible. The "home" isn't defined by one variable, but rather by where an NPC's many AI packages make them go throughout the day. "Home" isn't a place to an NPC in the game code, it's a set of behaviour scripts, and every NPC has different sets of scripts.